# In Ember Data force a route to always reload the children of a model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Since Ember data 1.13 it has been easy to force a route to reload its model, you use the reload: true option:

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.findRecord('order', params.order_id, { reload: true });
},
```

This is fine, and now I know my order is up to date. But what about children of the order. Say an order has order items. How do I force those to reload from the server too? I'm looking for code that will hit the api once per order item - whether hitting this route cleanly, without having seen those order items before, or when getting to the route, having seen those order items before.

I'm thinking after model hook but didn't know best practice here..

Comment: if you can change your api response you could always sideload all the children. That's what works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches have been outlined by Jeff above and in Slack.

**Approach 1**

Sideload the children.

**Approach 2**

Reload individually for each child.

Prior to Ember Data 2.5, I would have envisaged using peekRecord, and if not null then do a reload.

In Ember Data 2.5beta I think you could do something like

```
let promiseArray = [];
if (order.hasMany('orderItems').value() !== null) {
  var ids = order.hasMany('orderItems').ids();

  ids.forEach(id => promiseArray.addObject(store.findRecord('orderItem', id, {reload: true})));
}
return Ember.RSVP.all(promiseArray);
```

I'll update this answer when 2.5 comes out stable.